# Storing a status for an entity - best practice

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have a core data entity called `Product` which has a one-to-many relationship with a `Receipt` entity.

The `Receipt` entity has a `status` attribute with a type of `Integer 16` which stores whether the receipt was:

- sent successfully
- not sent
- requested to send but failed

I have defined `ReceiptStatus` as below

```
typedef enum ReceiptStatus : int16_t {
    InvalidReceiptStatus, 
    ReceiptStatusNoneSent,
    ReceiptStatusAttemptedButFailed,
    ReceiptStatusSentSuccessfully,
} ReceiptStatus;
```

Here comes my question... Is this a good idea? Would it be preferable to create another entity in my model called `ReceiptStatus` to using `typedef enum ReceiptStatus`?  My thoughts are that the way I currently have it is easier and more flexible.

Is there a better way to do this than the two options I've thought of?

I'm not sure if I'm somehow shooting myself in the foot by implementing it this way.  I'm at a point in the project where changing this is no big deal so I'd like to get it right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should mention that often StackOverflowers frown on “is this a good idea?” questions, but I rather like them.

Anyhow, yes, I think it’s a great idea. Don’t make your database unnecessarily slow and complex. Make it as simple as it can be.

Comment: I can see why it's frowned upon if it is in fact the best way to do it - but it seems the best community to get a good answer.